# Icon on Qt main windows not to set

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am new on Qt and **Qt designer**. My os is **ubuntu 18.4** and I am using **qt5**. I created a simple Qwindows by qt designer(Qt designer installed by default). For first step I want to change main window's icon so in order to I change icon attribute like this:
[image]

But when I preview it in designer this icon not seen? 
I converted this UI to py and this section to set icon:

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("res/main.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
```

After running this python code again not seen icon:

[image]

What is the problem?

My Qt designer **version is 5.9.5**

Comment: the ubuntu theme removes the topbar icon, that has nothing to do with PyQt.

Comment: I do up vote to @a_manthey_67 because it's answer.

Comment: I have not indicated that the answer to this post is wrong, I have pointed out that there is a question that I already deal with this topic so if you can do it then do it. :-)

Comment: According those topic i found out ubuntu seems do not show qt icon app.@eyllanesc

Answer (score 2):

you could try:

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    [..]
    icon = QtGui.QIcon(path_to_image)
    MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
```

Comment: dude i am using QMainwindow so i got `'QMainWindow' object has no attribute 'setIcon'`@BrandonBailey

Comment: my bad, i copied the code from a GUI i have to hand, just replace setIcon with : setWindowIcon

Comment: you have to make sure the path in QIcon is registered as a path, so if you're string slicing make sure you wrap it in an os.path.join()

Comment: Yes i am sure because this icon is appear on os toolbar when i run app. But this image not appear beside `config server title`.This is result of print(scriptDir + os.path.sep +'res/' + 'main.png') . `/home/groot/PycharmProjects/ConfigServer/res/main.png` @BrandonBailey

Comment: seems everything was `ok` and this is `ubuntu` stuff .Thanks dude and sorry i wasting you'r time .@BrandonBailey

Comment: no worries, glad its sorted!

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
...
MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/pyqt.jpg"))
...
```

Comment: I used `scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) 
  MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(scriptDir + os.path.sep +'res/' + 'main.png'))` but this icon is not appeared beside `config server` title @S.Nick

Comment: What is the result of the output line `print(scriptDir + os.path.sep +'res/' + 'main.png')` ?

Comment: `/home/groot/PycharmProjects/ConfigServer/res/main.png` @S.Nick

Comment: try it: `MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('./res/' + 'main.png'))`

Comment: bro as you can see icon is seen on the left side of picture and toolbar but not seen on the beside the title http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=a9cbe87eea17b4d911cac8ca5d46f523 @S.Nick

Comment: seems everything was `ok` and this is `ubuntu` stuff .Thanks dude and sorry i wasting you'r time .@S.Nick